# Tomcat vs Dropwizard Performance Comparison

Tags: jetty, tomcat7, dropwizard

I have been working on measuring performance for a dropwizard application. I am using Apache Bench to comparing performance.

For simplicity, I created 2 applications, one with dropwizard (main method and a one GET resource) and other tomcat application with a doGet method returning just "OK". Both the applications are not doing any operations so memory is not a performance factor here.

All server parameters are default in both Tomcat and dropwizard. I have not made any performance tuning.

I am running the server and apache bench on separate machines (both windows i-5 4 core 8GB)

When I run Apache Bench I get vastly different results.

For tomcat application

> Concurrency Level:      5
>
> Time taken for tests:   2.000 seconds
>
> Complete requests:      7000
>
> Failed requests:        0
>
> Write errors:           0
>
> Total transferred:      861000 bytes
>
> HTML transferred:       14000 bytes
>
> Requests per second:    **3499.97 [#/sec] (mean)**
>
> Time per request:       1.429 [ms] (mean)
>
> Time per request:       0.286 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent
>   requests)
>
> Transfer rate:          420.41 [Kbytes/sec] received

And for dropwizard application

> Concurrency Level:      5
>
> Time taken for tests:   6.444 seconds
>
> Complete requests:      7000
>
> Failed requests:        0
>
> Write errors:           0
>
> Total transferred:      1197000 bytes
>
> HTML transferred:       14000 bytes
>
> Requests per second:    **1086.28 [#/sec] (mean)**
>
> Time per request:       4.603 [ms] (mean)
>
> Time per request:       0.921 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent
>   requests)
>
> Transfer rate:          181.40 [Kbytes/sec] received

After this, I tried modifying performance tuning parameters such as, maxThreads, maxConnections for dropwizard. But still the throughput did not change much for the same test (concurrency 5).

So now, the question is, is there a major difference in the way tomcat handles input requests and how dropwizard (underlying Jetty) handles it?

One observation - number of bytes transferred from dropwizard is way more than same from tomcat. Printing verbose output from apache bench, it indicates that additional headers such as vary: accept-encoding is getting added. I am not sure if more bytes to transfer is leading to slow response time and in turn low throughput?

Please share your thoughts

Comment: Seems like a better question for ServerExchange.  StackOverflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Hi Thanks for this... Can you clarify what stack your tomcat application was built on.  Was it a spring/spring boot app with associated stack or something else?

Comment: Thanks. This was not a spring app. Just simple dropwizard application.

Comment: Tomcat application was a simple servlet.

Comment: I think this is not a fair comparison. Tomcat is a servlet container while dropwizard is a framework to build web services. The equivalent to Tomcat is the bundled Jetty servlet container in dropwizard. To make a fair comparison you would need to write a webapp for tomcat that matches the features of dropwizard, like Jackson, Jersey and others.

Comment: You are right Ralf. I meant to compare tomcat and jetty only. I did mention in this in my question - dropwizard (underlying Jetty). To have a fair comparison, I just wrote simple GET method in dropwizard and a servlet GET method in tomcat. The comparison I posted is between Jetty and tomcat.

Comment: For reference you could have a look at https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/ Dropwizard didn't run for Round 10, but the previous rounds can give you a good indication of performance